# Processing/Java File Count Issue With File Pathway (Variable Type)

Tags: java, file, syntax-error

Although the Title isn't very understandable I do have a simple issue. So i'm trying to write some code in a Processing Sketch (https://processing.org/) which can count how many files are in a document. The problem is, is that it doesn't accept the variable type.

```
File folder = File("My File Path");
folder.listFiles().size;
```

It says the function File(String) doesn't exist. When I try to put the file path without quation marks, it still doesn't work!

If you have a solution then please use a functioning example so that I know how it works. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "My File Path" folder is inside your sketch you need to provide the path to your sketch. Luckily Processing already provides a helper function: [`sketchPath()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#sketchPath-java.lang.String-)

Here's an example:

```
File folder = new File(sketchPath("My File Path"));
println("folder.exists: " + folder.exists());
if(folder.exists()){
  println(folder.listFiles().length + " files and/or directories");
}else{
  println("folder does not exist, double check the path");
}
```

Bare in mind there's also a [`dataPath()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#dataPath-java.lang.String-) function which points to a folder named **data** in your sketch folder. The **data** folder is typically used for storing external data (e.g. assets (raster or vector images/Processing font files) or raw data (binary/text/csv/xml/json/etc.)). This is useful to separate your sketch source files from the data to be loaded/accessed by your sketch.

Also, Processing has a few utility functions for listing files and folders.
Be sure to check out **Processing > Examples > Topics > File IO > DirectoryList**

The example includes less documented functions such as [`listFiles()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#listFiles-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) (which returns an array of java.io.File objects based on the filters set) or [`listPaths`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#listPaths-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) (which returns an array of String objects: just the paths).

The options and filters are quite handy, for example if you want to list directories only and ignore files you can simply write simply like:

```
println("directories: " + listFiles(sketchPath("My File Path"),"directories").length);
```

For example if want to list all the wav files in a `data/audio` directory inside the sketch you can use:

```
File[] files = listFiles(dataPath("audio"), "files", "extension=wav");
```

This will ignore directories and any other file that does not have .wav extension.

To make this answer complete, here are a few more details on the options for `listFiles`/`listPaths` from [Processing's source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L6691):

- `"relative" -> no effect with the Files version, but important for listPaths`
- `"recursive"-> traverse nested directories`
- `"extension=js" or "extensions=js|csv|txt" (no dot)`
- `"directories" -> only directories`
- `"files" -> only files`
- `"hidden" -> include hidden files (prefixed with .) disabled by default`

Comment: This seems to be the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537114/processing-java-i-need-a-file-path-to-the-actual-sketch-code-not-the-processin) asked by OP

Comment: It **should** (famous last words :) ), but it's very strange points where the processing executable lives, not the sketch, based on how the OP phrased that question. Let's see what information the OP can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's a constructor so you need to use `new`

```
File folder = new File("My File Path");
//To get the number of files in the folder
folder.listFiles().length;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it! But one quick question, could you show me how I would look at how many files are in just the folder the actual sketch/code is in without having to call the whole file path?

Comment: folder.listFiles().length

Comment: @MorganS42 did that help?

Comment: I've been working on it and i'm able to call the file where the sketch is located but it requires a whole file path. Do you think you would be able to help me locate the file without having to use a whole file path. For example I want it so that if I used the same code on a different computer, in a random file, it would still work. I've tried using sketchPath() and dataPath() but they just give me a path to where my processing.exe is stored (I want it to show a path to the actual code). I know it's a long question but any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: @MorganS42, Sorry but this sounds like a completely different question. I suggest  you post a new question describing this specific issue in detail.

Comment: I know and I did but I asked it here anyways to see if you could help, here's the page to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537114/processing-java-i-need-a-file-path-to-the-actual-sketch-code-not-the-processin.

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim Danielson says it is constructor so you need to use `new` keyword.
Below code will work for you.

```
File folder = new File("My File Path");
int fileLength = folder.listFiles().length;
```